# Add new field in the PriceDisc Journal and get it on Salesorder line

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I added one field in the `Pricedisc` journal. Once the `TradeAgreement` is posted, the field will be updated in the `PriceDisc` Table.

Now, I need to get the same field on the `SalesOrder` form based on `pricegroup`.

Is there any standard way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [Cross Reference tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa626961.aspx)?

Search how the standard fields are moved.